# Estimated Time Between two Locations(Lattitude & Longitude) in iOS using Google API

Tags: ios, google-maps

I Have google api link from two locations

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&mode=driving&origin=12.9862449,80.2094988&destination=12.9229153,80.1274558&sensor=false

i get the response from two locations(distance&time) its working fine, but we need with traffic and without traffic details using google api's.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=en#RequestParameters

> For requests where the travel mode is transit: You can optionally
>   specify one of departure_time or arrival_time. If neither time is
>   specified, the departure_time defaults to now (that is, the departure
>   time defaults to the current time).
>
> For requests where the travel mode is driving: You can specify the
>   departure_time to receive a route and trip duration (response field:
>   duration_in_traffic) that take traffic conditions into account. This
>   option is only available if the request contains a valid API key, or a
>   valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature. The
>   departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the
>   future. It cannot be in the past.
>
> traffic_model (defaults to best_guess) — Specifies the assumptions to
>   use when calculating time in traffic. This setting affects the value
>   returned in the duration_in_traffic field in the response, which
>   contains the predicted time in traffic based on historical averages.
>   The traffic_model parameter may only be specified for requests where
>   the travel mode is driving, and where the request includes a
>   departure_time, and only if the request includes an API key or a
>   Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID. The available values for this
>   parameter are: best_guess (default) indicates that the returned
>   duration_in_traffic should be the best estimate of travel time given
>   what is known about both historical traffic conditions and live
>   traffic. Live traffic becomes more important the closer the
>   departure_time is to now.
>
> pessimistic indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be
>   longer than the actual travel time on most days, though occasional
>   days with particularly bad traffic conditions may exceed this value.
>
> optimistic indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be
>   shorter than the actual travel time on most days, though occasional
>   days with particularly good traffic conditions may be faster than this
>   value.